# How to stop propagating from event handler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that triggers an event on a click. Then I have a subscriber to that event. Inside the subscriber's event handler if certain condition is true then I want to stop processing everything inside button's click event.

I tried calling  `e.preventDefault()`,  `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` but nothing works.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  // trigger event
  console.log("triggering event");

  $(document).trigger("response.beforeSave");

  //I want to stop processing after this when subscriber invokes preventDefault() or 
  //stopPropagation()

  console.log("after trigger. This should not get invoked.");
})

$(document).off("response.beforeSave").on("response.beforeSave", function(e) {
  console.log("start subscriber");

  if (true) // if condition is true
  {
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return;
  }

  console.log("exit subscriber. This should not get invoked.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Would a `return` statement satisfies you need?

Comment: the only way to stop the execution of a function (which your click handler is), is to return from it.

Comment: Document already responded to that custom `"response.beforeSave"` event - makes no sense to stop propagation. Usually stopping an event propagation is a bad idea. Every part of an application should always be notified of occurring events. Or I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish...?!

Comment: The seems like it could be solved by utilising better code structure, instead of `preventDefault()`/`stopPropagation()`/a variable to control external function flow.

Comment: You want to know if an event you triggered got cancelled? You probably want to rethink how you are coding this. That is an odd pattern.

Comment: I thought the code self explain what I am trying to achieve, but basically I want to stop further processing of click event when subscriber notifies. What are my other options?

Comment: @thedude `return` would work but publisher need to know when to return. Its the subscriber who decides. and somehow it needs to inform event publisher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own [Event Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and pass that to the `.trigger` rather than a string with the event name.

This will allow you to check what happened to the event.

An example exists on the jQuery [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) page

```
var event = jQuery.Event( "submit" );
$( "form" ).first().trigger( event );
if ( event.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
  // Perform an action...
}
```

Here's your code updated to match:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
  // trigger event
  console.log("triggering event");

  // create a new event object 
  var beforeSaveEvent = jQuery.Event("response.beforeSave");
  $(document).trigger(beforeSaveEvent);
  
  if (beforeSaveEvent.isImmediatePropagationStopped()) {
    console.log("event stopped");
    
    // can also check beforeSaveEvent.isDefaultPrevented
    // can also check beforeSaveEvent.isPropagationStopped
    
    // e is the click event - function(e) above
    // could also use `event` here
    // "cancel" the click event    
    e.stopPropagation();
    return;
  }

  console.log("after trigger. This should not get invoked.");
})

$(document).off("response.beforeSave").on("response.beforeSave", function(e) {
  console.log("start subscriber");

  if (true) // if condition is true
  {
    // whichever is used, check the equivalent event.isXXX
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return;
  }

  console.log("exit subscriber. This should not get invoked.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Its worked.  However we have to use `isImmediatePropagationStopped` as function not property `if (beforeSaveEvent.isImmediatePropagationStopped())`

Answer (score 1):

To put it simple, here's a suggestion by passing arbitrary data (a boolean in your case) via the second parameter of `.trigger("EventNamespace", [])`

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function(evt) { 
  const canSave = document.querySelector("[name=canSave]").checked;
  $(document).trigger("response.beforeSave", [{canSave}]);

  console.log(`Handler before: canSave is ${canSave}`);
  if (!canSave) return;
  console.log(`Handler after`);
});

$(document).on("response.beforeSave", function(evt, data) {
  if (!data.canSave) return;
  console.log(`Subscriber: canSave is ${data.canSave}`);
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="canSave"> toggle "canSave"</label><br>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: place `$(document).trigger` before (like in the example) **or after** the `if(canSave)` statement - depending on what you need.

Comment: I ended up passing the arbitrary data. But I attached the data to event `var beforeSaveEvent = jQuery.Event("response.beforeSave");
        beforeSaveEvent.canSave = true;
        $(document).trigger(beforeSaveEvent);`  and then in handler set `evt.canSave = false`

Comment: @LP13 yes, that's exactly what you can do by passing data around via that param. Preventing, stopping propagations is almost never a good pattern approach. I really advice for the above solution.